# How to insert comment in iMacros script?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, ui-automation, imacros

How to insert comment in `iMacros` script? What is a the combination of characters to achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [http://wiki.imacros.net/'_(Comment)](http://wiki.imacros.net/%27_%28Comment%29)

`The single quote character ' indicates a comment.`

Answer (score 4):

You can also use Ctrl + Q and comment multiple lines.

```
'type you comment here
'and here as well
```